# Kotlin Returned variable doesnt get passed

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I tried to search for a solution but I can't find one. I have these function that is inherited from an interface, and when I try to return the variable to fill up the empty variable it doesn't get passed from info 4. can someone please help me why it doesn't get passed?

```kotlin
class chooseRace(): adventuringBasics {

    override val variable: String = " "

    override fun PrintOut() {
        println("Your race is $variable")
    }

    override fun info2(selects: String) {
    }

    override fun info6(lvl: Int) {
    }


    override fun info3(last: String) {
    }

    //Race Selector
    override fun info4(type: Int):String {
        when (type) {
            1 -> variable == "Human"
            2 -> variable == "Orc"
            3 -> variable == "Elf"
            4 -> variable == "Demon Kin"
            5 -> variable == "Beast Folk"
            else -> variable == "None Chosen"
        }
        return variable;
    }

    override fun info5(selects: Int) {
    }
}
```

Comment: `==` is the equality operator, not the assignment operator.

Comment: Your problem is that you are not assigning anything to `variable`
That `variable` is strange on it's won. You have function that have an input and an output parameter but also modifies a class level declaration? João Dias solution will work for you, but I would rethink how this class works.

Comment: One particular issue with the current design is that it's not thread-safe; if two threads call `info4()`, then (assuming you've replaced the `==`s with `=`) one thread could get the other's result. If `variable` is genuinely part of the object's state, you'd expect to see it used elsewhere (and protected); right now it should probably be a local variable inside `info4()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

```kotlin
override fun info4(type: Int):String {
    variable = when (type) {
        1 -> "Human"
        2 -> "Orc"
        3 -> "Elf"
        4 -> "Demon Kin"
        5 -> "Beast Folk"
        else -> "None Chosen"
    }
    return variable;
}
```

This will work, but just like @Alex just added as a comment to your question the class design does not seem right. Consider rework it.

Comment: Reworking the class design, thank you!